# django urls.py structure for login, logout, signup ( not app-specific urls ) : in users app or project default app?

Tags: django, django-urls

## Question

I am managing a small django project. and our team has conflicting opinions about this problem :

> which is recommended way to put login, logout, signup ( not app-specific routers )?

```
   # Login, Logout
    url(r'^login/$', 'users.views.login_view', name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'users.views.logout_view', name='logout'),
    url(r'^signup/$', 'users.views.signup', name='signup'),
```

### 1. `MY_PROJECT` > `urls.py`

> Reason : should see overall urls in `MY_PROJECT/urls.py` and login, logout, signup is not app-specific urls.

### 2. `users` > `urls.py`

> Reason : should move login, logout, signup to users app, because view is implemented in `users/views.py`, and it is preferred way in the view of modularity.

## Folder Structure

```
.
├── MY_PROJECT
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── users
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

## Additional Information for implemetation

Users app is for extending base User using UserProfile

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    and so on ...
```

and also, expending default login, logout, signup view. for example :

```
def login_view(request):
    return default_login_view(
        request, template_name="users/login.html"
    )


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect("home")
```

Comment: i know that there is no right answer. but i want to know how other programmers think about this issue. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you put all general urls of your project in MY_PROJECT/urls.py after a while number of lines of this file increases a lot. Then when you need to track a specific url, looking through this file could be hard.

So if all urls in MY_PROJECT/urls.py be in following format, you can save a lot of time in searching for a specific url and your code is more cleaner too.

```
(r'^foo/', include('foo.urls')),
```

But if your **users** app is large, maybe if you use a seperate **urls.py** for login/logout/signup be a better approach. It means in your **users** app put **urls.py** and **auth_urls.py** seperate.